# Como remover preenchimento automático de inputs?

Tags: html

Tenho meus input de email/senha. Mas sempre ao digitar um email a qual eu já tenho salvo login/senha, o navegador preenche automaticamente no meu formulário.

Como resolver?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Não deixar navegador salvar a senha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/298747/3635)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Em princípio, a solução seria simples, colocar o `autocomplete="off"` tanto no `form` quanto no `input`:

  ```
  <form name="meuform" id="meuform" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
  <input type="text" name="batatinha" autocomplete="off">
  ```

  Lembrando que `autocomplete` é `HTML5`, não se esqueça de trabalhar com o `doctype` correto no topo da página:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  ```

Mas como já dito nos comentários e em [outras fontes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/), nem todos os browsers reagem da mesma forma. Para isto, há uma série de saídas e *reparos técnicos* <sup>1</sup> a se considerar:

- Uma delas, é acrescentar dois campos escondidos por CSS logo no começo do form:

  ```
  <form name="meuform" id="meuform" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
  <input type="text" style="display:none">
  <input type="password" style="display:none">
  ```

  Alguns browsers entendem que por ter dois campos senha, o formulário é de troca de senha, então ignoram o autocomplete.
- Outra é preencher o form com "nada" usando JS ou JQuery, por exemplo:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){ $('input[type="text"], select').val('') });
  ```
- Alternativamente, você pode randomizar os `names` e `id`s do form com alguma linguagem server-side.

### Considerações:

- Algumas extensões e *password managers* ignoram completamente o  atributo `autocomplete`.
- Considere a usabilidade, e os reais motivos de desabilitar esta função. Provavelmente você tem uma boa razão para evitar o *autocomplete*, mas não se esqueça de pensar em todos os prós e contras.

### O outro lado da moeda:

Para os casos em que você queira o autocomplete em um campo só (nos browsers que respeitam o *autocomplete*, claro, dá pra "desligar" no `form` todo e "ligar" no campo desejado:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input name="username">
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <input name="another_field" autocomplete="on">
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: coloquei autocomplete no form inteiro... e mesmo assim

Comment: +1. Vale mencionar que `autocomplete="off"` funciona com qualquer campo do tipo `input`, assim como `textarea`s.

Comment: @Rod E mesmo assim o que?

Comment: 'Tip: In some browsers you may need to activate an autocomplete function for this to work (Look under "Preferences" in the browser's menu)'. Já tive problema com isso, se não me engano no Firefox.

Comment: @Rod tente aplicar diretamente no `<form>`, ou seja `<form autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Eu apliquei no form, e não no input, e mesmo assim continua preenchendo os valores...

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
<input type="text" id="matricula" placeholder="Matrícula" name="mat" required
    autofocus autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />

<input type="password" id="senha" placeholder="Senha" name="pass" required
    autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"
    onBlur="this.setAttribute('readonly', true);" />
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu observei o seguinte, no internet explorer não funciona direito, adicionei uma ação a mais:

```
<input type="text" id="matricula" placeholder="Matrícula" name="mat" required
    autofocus autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');this.select();" />

<input type="password" id="senha" placeholder="Senha" name="pass" required
    autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');this.select();" />
```

Não vi necessidade do evento onBlur, funcionou perfeitamente, testei, mas não houve efeito, como desenvolvo também para mobile, o funcionamento ocorreu normalmente.

Eu ainda fui além, usando jquery, consegui manter a cor natural do campo, que geralmente é branca, com o seguinte comando:

```
$("#matricula").css('background-color', '#ffffff');
$("#senha").css('background-color', '#ffffff');
```

Answer (score 1):

passei pelo mesmo problema, hoje 10/09/2019 única solução que encontrei foi essa

colocar 2 inputs falsos antes do seu input

```
<input class="hidden" type="text" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
<input class="hidden" type="password" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
```

Answer (score -3):

Eu estava tendo problemas com o prrenchimento automatico da microsoft no angular

Resolvi com css

```css
#autofillAddressDropdown{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Caso alguém tenha problemas com alguma outra extessão de preenchimento automático eu sugiro inspecionar o elemento e eliminar o problema com css

Answer (score -4):

Para mim funcionou:

```
autocomplete="none"
```

Usando no Ionic5