# Impedir Autocomplete do navegador na senha

Tags: html, segurança, input, navegador-de-internet, autocompletar

Tenho uma tela de bloqueio que desloga o usuario por inatividade, pedindo apenas a senha do mesmo para acessar novamente. Acontece que essa tela não tem serventia nenhuma se autocomplete estiver ligado, já que qualquer um pode mexer nesse pc e entrar na conta desse usuario. Pesquisei muito e vi que o `autocomplete="off"`, por exemplo, já está sendo ignorado pelos navegadores.

Alguém sabe um método funcional para solucionar esse problema? Por JQuery, um plugin qualquer coisa do tipo. Ou realmente só o cliente desabilitando a opção de guarda senha?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como remover preenchimento automático de inputs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33482/como-remover-preenchimento-autom%c3%a1tico-de-inputs)

Answer (score 0):

Os navegadores provavelmente só completam o primeiro campo de senha, tente adicionar um campo de senha invisível (`style="opacity: 0;position: absolute"`) e depois insira no código o que realmente irá usar.

Answer (score -3):

Como o atributo autocomplete não é válido pela W3C é comum inserir o autocomplete="off" via javascript:

```
// Utilizando JQuery
jQuery('campo').attr('autocomplete','off');
// Ou Javascript padrão
campo.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
```

Pode-se utilizar a solução do javascript para adicionar esse atributo em campos do ADF e/ou elementos onde não temos acesso direto ao código HTML gerado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).