# Dropdown do elemento input do tipo texto com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo uma página de login, mas o estilo do dropdown do `<input>` muda em cada navegador. Eu andei pesquisando e descobri que não tem como mudar o estilo dele com CSS, pois aquele estilo é próprio de cada navegador.

Nas minhas pesquisas encontrei, ainda, que é possível mudar o estilo do dropdown do `<select>` usando javascript, mas nada referente ao `<input>`. (Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp)

Quando salvo diversos logins e senhas, aparece um dropdown no `<input name="user" id="user" type="text">`. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de mudar aquele estilo com javascript? Obrigado!

```html
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="login"><br />
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" value="Send">
<form>
```

Comment: Paulo eu fiquei meio confuso, vc apenas quer estilizar um input, ou vc está falando que vc tem um JS que transforma o seu input em um dropdown?

Comment: Não é possível não. Aquele "dropdown" (na verdade não é dropdown, é uma espécie de "autocomplete" ou dica que o navegador dá ao ir armazenando o que foi digitado) é recurso do navegador e não pode ser modificado.

Comment: @hugocsl Não e não (rs). Seria mais o "autocomplete do navegador" de que quero mudar o estilo.

Comment: @sam Que pena! Eu estava olhando o js do exemplo da w3schools, mas ele basicamente constroi cada item do `<select>` usando html e css.

Comment: Se vc está falando do autocomplete que o navegado mostra vc tb não vai conseguir customiza-lo pelo mesmo fato do select. Principalmente o campo password que tem várias limitações... Em inputs normais o `autocomplete="off"` pode funcionar, mas no pass não vai rolar... Agora se vc quer simplesmente customizar um input text ai existem 1000 maneiras....

Comment: @hugocsl Você me entendeu da primeira vez. Pensei que tivesse como costumizar o autocomplete mesmo. Vou manter o post aberto, para ver se alguém tem alguma ideia de burlar este mecanismo. Obrigado!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33482/como-remover-preenchimento-autom%C3%A1tico-de-inputs/33490#33490

Comment: @hugocsl Perfeito! Não resolve o problema do estilo, mas traz diversas manobras bacanas. Muito obrigado por me indicar aquela postagem! Eu jamais pesquisaria formas de barrar o autocomplete, então seria difícil eu encontrar aquela pergunta. Obrigado mais uma vez! Poste sua resposta na resposta para eu marcar ela como "solução".

Comment: Paulo de nada, estamos aqui para contribuir. Não verdade eu não tenho outra resposta que não pegar a resposta do outro poste. Então o correto para o funcionamento do StackOverflow é votar para fechar a pergunta como Duplicada. Vc mesmo pode aceitar a marcação de Duplicada, ou se não quiser ela automaticamente vai para fila de análise e a Comunidade vai votar para fecha-la ou não...

Comment: @hugocsl Entendi! Tudo bem! Obrigado novamente! :)